# Staggered collections in Android app

Tags: android, design-patterns, collections, android-listview, android-gridview

Hi I just watch the last video of [Android Design in Action: Collections](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6jMnYwjftk&feature=share&list=PLi1Skx1i6X3Fh1sKCcRh9DGnPysUdhTrz) and I would like how do you approach the following view:

[image]

The first thing that I though was use a GridView, but how do you achieve the first item fill two items size?

The other solution that I think is use a normal ListView, but in each row return two items view. And for the first row return a single item.

What do you think about these two approach? There are a better options?

**UPDATE:**

I want to inflate the collection dynamically from a Cursor or a List.

Comment: in a GridLayout you can use `colspan=2` and `rowspan=2`, maybe that'll help you

Comment: But I want inflate the view from a Cursor dynamically. In terms of performance use a Layout is not the best options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the link..

http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/

in that link have Staggeredgridview example with source code try that..

https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo

Comment: Is not the same scenario, because in StaggeredGridView the height is variable, but I want the width variable

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same scenario, but you may find this post useful.-

[Create gridlayout.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955452/create-gridlayout/18955580#18955580)

Comment: Is more less the same scenario, but I fill the items from a Cursor so using LinearLayout is not a good option in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you my friend. Use the following library https://github.com/Utopia-Developers/StaggeredGridView Its an implementation of StaggeredGridView that allows you to set column span on each view in the getView() method of your adapter.[image: Implementation of the StaggeredGridView from Utopia developers]

Comment: You don't help so much

Comment: Well StaggeredGridView library was never intended for this task although you may achieve the desired result by hacking around a bit. However you should look into http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html. Someone may have made a layout manager for this exact requirement. If I find a layout manager for this I will post but you should look into this.

Comment: Have a look at this layout manager https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/blob/master/layouts/src/main/java/org/lucasr/twowayview/widget/SpannableGridLayoutManager.java

You can use it directly with recyclerview or with the entire abstraction library Lucas has built.

Read abt it here
http://lucasr.org/2014/07/31/the-new-twowayview/